# QAudioInput from array

Tags: c++, qt, streaming, qt5

I have a device with microphones that connects to my computer through Ethernet and it cannot be seen by Qt as an audio device, so, I get packets from it and put them to QByteArray. I need to play these packets from stream. Somewhere in the Internet I found a solution to almost the same problem, but there internal microphone was used.

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QAudioInput>
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QBuffer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QBuffer rdBuff;
    QBuffer wrBuff;
    wrBuff.open(QBuffer::WriteOnly);
    rdBuff.open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);

    QObject::connect(&wrBuff, &QIODevice::bytesWritten, [&wrBuff, &rdBuff](qint64)
    {
        rdBuff.buffer().remove(0, rdBuff.pos());

        // set pointer to the beginning of the unread data
        const auto res = rdBuff.seek(0);
        assert(res);

        // write new data
        rdBuff.buffer().append(wrBuff.buffer());

        // remove all data that was already written
        wrBuff.buffer().clear();
        wrBuff.seek(0);
    });

    const auto decideAudioFormat = [](const QAudioDeviceInfo& devInfo)
    {
        QAudioFormat format;
        format.setSampleRate(8000);
        format.setChannelCount(1);
        format.setSampleSize(16);
        format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
        format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
        format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

        if (devInfo.isFormatSupported(format))
        {
            return format;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play audio.\n";
            throw 0;
        }
    };

    QAudioInput audioInput(decideAudioFormat(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice()));
    QAudioOutput audioOutput(decideAudioFormat(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice()));

    audioInput.start(&wrBuff);
    audioOutput.start(&rdBuff);

    return app.exec();
}
```

It works quite well, but I need to set QByteArray as QAudioInput's source.
Is there any possible solution?

Comment: Does this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuffer.html#setBuffer answer your question?

Comment: No, it sets buffer at once but QAudioInput does it continuously during playback, moreover it doesn't emit QIODevice::bytesWritten and emitting it manually leads to not playing record at all. Should I do appending buffer and playback in separate threads?

Comment: Can you call `QBuffer::setBuffer` from the top lambda in your source code so that it replaces current way you update the buffer. I mean `QBuffer::setBuffer` will push in one portion of data. Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I continuously get "QBuffer::setBuffer: Buffer is open" message and no playback.

Comment: @Андрей Садков: Do you need an `QAudioInput` device or just want to play data of `QByteArray` with `QAudioOutput` device?

Comment: @АндрейСадков: maybe just recreate QBuffer object pointing to new QByteArray.

Comment: @Alexander V: the same error.

Comment: @Antonio Dias: Actually, I don't need to use QAudioInput, I just thought that it could help cause it can record during a playback but it needs a microphone as a device. My vision is that I can connect the microphone through QTcpSocket and put it into a QThread while playback stays in the main thread, so, I can make some kind of a custom QAudioInput. The idea was to find out, if there is an easier way to do this using just built-in classes and methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if i'm directly answering your question. But a possible solution is feed the output audio device manually (push mode) when new data comes.

You can also use a custom (QFile inherited) class to record sound, and when sound come, feeds both the file and output audio device.

Here is a example:

AudioOutput.h:

```
#ifndef AUDIOOUTPUT_H
#define AUDIOOUTPUT_H

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtMultimedia>

#define MAX_BUFFERED_TIME 10*1000

static inline int timeToSize(int ms, const QAudioFormat &format)
{
    return ((format.channelCount() * (format.sampleSize() / 8) * format.sampleRate()) * ms / 1000);
}

class AudioOutput : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit AudioOutput(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    bool start(const QAudioDeviceInfo &devinfo,
               const QAudioFormat &format,
               int time_to_buffer);

    void write(const QByteArray &data);

private slots:
    void verifyBuffer();
    void preplay();
    void play();

private:
    bool m_initialized;
    QAudioOutput *m_audio_output;
    QIODevice *m_device;
    QByteArray m_buffer;
    bool m_buffer_requested;
    bool m_play_called;
    int m_size_to_buffer;
    int m_time_to_buffer;
    int m_max_size_to_buffer;
    QAudioFormat m_format;
};

#endif // AUDIOOUTPUT_H
```

AudioRecorder.h:

```
#ifndef AUDIORECORDER_H
#define AUDIORECORDER_H

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtMultimedia>

class AudioRecorder : public QFile
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit AudioRecorder(const QString &name, const QAudioFormat &format, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~AudioRecorder();

    using QFile::open;

public slots:
    bool open();
    qint64 write(const QByteArray &data);
    void close();

private:
    void writeHeader();
    bool hasSupportedFormat();
    QAudioFormat format;
};

#endif // AUDIORECORDER_H
```

AudioOutput.cpp:

```
#include "audiooutput.h"

AudioOutput::AudioOutput(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_initialized = false;
    m_audio_output = nullptr;
    m_device = nullptr;
    m_buffer_requested = true;
    m_play_called = false;
    m_size_to_buffer = 0;
    m_time_to_buffer = 0;
    m_max_size_to_buffer = 0;
}

bool AudioOutput::start(const QAudioDeviceInfo &devinfo,
                        const QAudioFormat &format,
                        int time_to_buffer)
{
    if (!devinfo.isFormatSupported(format))
    {
        qDebug() << "Format not supported by output device";
        return m_initialized;
    }

    m_format = format;

    int internal_buffer_size;

    //Adjust internal buffer size
    if (format.sampleRate() >= 44100)
        internal_buffer_size = (1024 * 10) * format.channelCount();
    else if (format.sampleRate() >= 24000)
        internal_buffer_size = (1024 * 6) * format.channelCount();
    else
        internal_buffer_size = (1024 * 4) * format.channelCount();

    //Initialize the audio output device
    m_audio_output = new QAudioOutput(devinfo, format, this);
    //Increase the buffer size to enable higher sample rates
    m_audio_output->setBufferSize(internal_buffer_size);

    m_time_to_buffer = time_to_buffer;
    //Compute the size in bytes to be buffered based on the current format
    m_size_to_buffer = timeToSize(m_time_to_buffer, m_format);
    //Define a highest size that the buffer are allowed to have in the given time
    //This value is used to discard too old buffered data
    m_max_size_to_buffer = m_size_to_buffer + timeToSize(MAX_BUFFERED_TIME, m_format);

    m_device = m_audio_output->start();

    if (!m_device)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to open output audio device";
        return m_initialized;
    }

    //Timer that helps to keep playing data while it's available on the internal buffer
    QTimer *timer_play = new QTimer(this);
    timer_play->setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
    connect(timer_play, &QTimer::timeout, this, &AudioOutput::preplay);
    timer_play->start(10);

    //Timer that checks for too old data in the buffer
    QTimer *timer_verifier = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer_verifier, &QTimer::timeout, this, &AudioOutput::verifyBuffer);
    timer_verifier->start(qMax(m_time_to_buffer, 10));

    m_initialized = true;

    return m_initialized;
}

void AudioOutput::verifyBuffer()
{
    if (m_buffer.size() >= m_max_size_to_buffer)
        m_buffer.clear();
}

void AudioOutput::write(const QByteArray &data)
{
    m_buffer.append(data);
    preplay();
}

void AudioOutput::preplay()
{
    if (!m_initialized)
        return;

    //Verify if exists a pending call to play function
    //If not, call the play function async
    if (!m_play_called)
    {
        m_play_called = true;
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "play", Qt::QueuedConnection);
    }
}

void AudioOutput::play()
{
    //Set that last async call was triggered
    m_play_called = false;

    if (m_buffer.isEmpty())
    {
        //If data is empty set that nothing should be played
        //until the buffer has at least the minimum buffered size already set
        m_buffer_requested = true;
        return;
    }
    else if (m_buffer.size() < m_size_to_buffer)
    {
        //If buffer doesn't contains enough data,
        //check if exists a already flag telling that the buffer comes
        //from a empty state and should not play anything until have the minimum data size
        if (m_buffer_requested)
            return;
    }
    else
    {
        //Buffer is ready and data can be played
        m_buffer_requested = false;
    }

    int readlen = m_audio_output->periodSize();

    int chunks = m_audio_output->bytesFree() / readlen;

    //Play data while it's available in the output device
    while (chunks)
    {
        //Get chunk from the buffer
        QByteArray samples = m_buffer.mid(0, readlen);
        int len = samples.size();
        m_buffer.remove(0, len);

        //Write data to the output device
        if (len)
            m_device->write(samples);

        //If chunk is smaller than the output chunk size, exit loop
        if (len != readlen)
            break;

        //Decrease the available number of chunks
        chunks--;
    }
}
```

AudioRecorder.cpp:

```
#include "audiorecorder.h"

AudioRecorder::AudioRecorder(const QString &name, const QAudioFormat &format, QObject *parent) : QFile(name, parent), format(format)
{

}

AudioRecorder::~AudioRecorder()
{
    if (!isOpen())
        return;

    close();
}

bool AudioRecorder::hasSupportedFormat()
{
    return (format.sampleSize() == 8
            && format.sampleType() == QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt)
            || (format.sampleSize() > 8
                && format.sampleType() == QAudioFormat::SignedInt
                && format.byteOrder() == QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
}

bool AudioRecorder::open()
{
    if (!hasSupportedFormat())
    {
        setErrorString("Wav PCM supports only 8-bit unsigned samples "
                       "or 16-bit (or more) signed samples (in little endian)");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!QFile::open(ReadWrite | Truncate))
            return false;
        writeHeader();
        return true;
    }
}

qint64 AudioRecorder::write(const QByteArray &data)
{
    return QFile::write(data);
}

void AudioRecorder::writeHeader()
{
    QDataStream out(this);
    out.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);

    // RIFF chunk
    out.writeRawData("RIFF", 4);
    out << quint32(0); // Placeholder for the RIFF chunk size (filled by close())
    out.writeRawData("WAVE", 4);

    // Format description chunk
    out.writeRawData("fmt ", 4);
    out << quint32(16); // "fmt " chunk size (always 16 for PCM)
    out << quint16(1); // data format (1 => PCM)
    out << quint16(format.channelCount());
    out << quint32(format.sampleRate());
    out << quint32(format.sampleRate() * format.channelCount()
                   * format.sampleSize() / 8 ); // bytes per second
    out << quint16(format.channelCount() * format.sampleSize() / 8); // Block align
    out << quint16(format.sampleSize()); // Significant Bits Per Sample

    // Data chunk
    out.writeRawData("data", 4);
    out << quint32(0); // Placeholder for the data chunk size (filled by close())

    Q_ASSERT(pos() == 44); // Must be 44 for WAV PCM
}

void AudioRecorder::close()
{
    // Fill the header size placeholders
    quint32 fileSize = size();

    QDataStream out(this);
    // Set the same ByteOrder like in writeHeader()
    out.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
    // RIFF chunk size
    seek(4);
    out << quint32(fileSize - 8);

    // data chunk size
    seek(40);
    out << quint32(fileSize - 44);

    QFile::close();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include "audiooutput.h"
#include "audiorecorder.h"
#include <signal.h>

QByteArray tone_generator()
{
    //Tone generator from http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/129827/

    const unsigned int samplerate = 8000;
    const unsigned short channels = 1;

    const double pi = M_PI;
    const qint16 amplitude = std::numeric_limits<qint16>::max() * 0.5;

    const unsigned short n_frequencies = 8;
    const unsigned short n_seconds_each = 1;

    float frequencies[n_frequencies] = {55.0, 110.0, 220.0, 440.0, 880.0, 1760.0, 3520.0, 7040.0};

    const int n_samples = channels * samplerate * n_frequencies * n_seconds_each;

    QVector<qint16> data;
    data.resize(n_samples);

    int index = n_samples / n_frequencies;

    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < n_frequencies; ++i)
    {
        float freq = frequencies[i];
        double d = (samplerate / freq);
        int c = 0;

        for (int j = index * i; j < index * (i + 1); j += 2)
        {
            double deg = 360.0 / d;
            data[j] = data[j + (channels - 1)] = qSin((c++ * deg) * pi / 180.0) * amplitude;
        }
    }

    return QByteArray((char*)data.data(), data.size() * sizeof(qint16));
}

void signalHandler(int signum)
{
    qDebug().nospace() << "Interrupt signal (" << signum << ") received.";

    qApp->exit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Handle console close to ensure destructors being called
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    signal(SIGBREAK, signalHandler);
#else
    signal(SIGHUP, signalHandler);
#endif
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setSampleRate(8000);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(16);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

    AudioOutput output;

    AudioRecorder file("tone.wav", format);

    if (!output.start(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice(), format, 10 * 1000)) //10 seconds of buffer
        return a.exec();

    if (!file.open())
    {
        qDebug() << qPrintable(file.errorString());
        return a.exec();
    }

    qDebug() << "Started!";

    QByteArray audio_data = tone_generator();

    QTimer timer;

    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&]{
        qDebug() << "Writting" << audio_data.size() << "bytes";
        output.write(audio_data);
        file.write(audio_data);
    });

    qDebug() << "Writting" << audio_data.size() << "bytes";
    output.write(audio_data);
    file.write(audio_data);

    timer.start(8000); //8 seconds because we generated 8 seconds of sound

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Generated signal sounds quite interesting. :) I'll try to adapt your code for my problem. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I tried to apply the code (just playback for now) to my situation but there is a problem that it plays data once, if there is no emitting "MorePackets()", or doesn't play at all, if "MorePackets()" occurs.

micserver.h

```
#ifndef MICSERVER_H
#define MICSERVER_H
//-----------------------------//
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QAudioFormat>
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QFile>
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDataStream>

#include <iostream>

#include "audiooutput.h"
//-----------------------------//
class MicServer : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MicServer(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QTcpSocket* Socket;
private:
    QTcpServer* Server;
    QAudioFormat format;
    AudioOutput output;

    QByteArray GetPackets(QTcpSocket* ClientP, int PacketsNumP);
signals:
    void MorePackets();

public slots:
    void NewConnection();
    void Play();
};
//-----------------------------//
#endif
```

micserver.cpp

```
#include "micserver.h"
//-----------------------------//
QByteArray MicServer :: GetPackets(QTcpSocket* ClientP, int PacketsNumP) {
    QBuffer BufferL;
    BufferL.open(QBuffer :: WriteOnly);
    QDataStream InputL(&BufferL);
    InputL.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_10);

    QByteArray TempArray;

    for (int i = 0; i < PacketsNumP; i++) {
        ClientP -> waitForReadyRead(3000);
        InputL << ClientP -> readAll();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < PacketsNumP; i++) {
        TempArray.push_back(BufferL.buffer().mid(76 + i * 1172, 256));
    }

    BufferL.close();

    return TempArray;
}
//-----------------------------//
MicServer :: MicServer(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
    Server = new QTcpServer;

    if (!Server -> listen(QHostAddress :: Any, 49112)) {
        qDebug() << "Failed to launch server!";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Server launched!";
    }

    connect(Server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(NewConnection()));
    connect(Server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(Play()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(MorePackets()), this, SLOT(Play()));

    format.setSampleRate(16000);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(16);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

    output.start(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice(), format);
}

void MicServer :: NewConnection() {
    Socket = Server -> nextPendingConnection();
    qDebug() << "New connection!";

    qDebug() << Socket -> localAddress().toString();
}

void MicServer :: Play() {
    QByteArray audio_data = GetPackets(Socket, 250);

    QTimer timer;

    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&]{
        qDebug() << "Writting" << audio_data.size() << "bytes";
        output.write(audio_data);
    });

    qDebug() << "Writting" << audio_data.size() << "bytes";
    output.write(audio_data);

    timer.start(2000);

    emit(MorePackets());
}
```

Comment: I will suggest you connect the `readyRead` SIGNAL when the client is handled in function `NewConnection()` to the SLOT `Play()`, then when new data comes use yours `GetPackets(Socket, 250)` or any function to read from the socket, and directly write to output device, `QTimer` not needed in your case!

Comment: @Antonio Dias: Thanks, it works! But it's strange that no matter how many packets I get before a playback, duration of the playback seems to have fixed value (I can't record a second and then play it), the ideal number of packets that leads to minimum freezes is approximately 25, not 250 (1 second of recording) that I used before. Why does it happen?

Comment: The `AudioOutput` class plays in realtime, no matter how much data you write to it, internally the data will be split in chunks to adjust for ininterrupt playback, so you can either write 250 packets of 1 millisecond or 25 packets of 10 milliseconds, in both cases you'll have 250 milliseconds, that will be played in the sequence you write to the class. What really matters is the amount of data! If i understood your question :)

Comment: In my situation I have the same amount of data in every packet. As you can see in the "GetPackets" function, every packet is 1172 bytes long and I get 256 bytes to play data from only one channel, so, increasing amount of packets leads to increasing amount of data. I thought that if I wrote more data, I'd get freezes less frequently. But it seems like in this case AudioOutput gets only small amount of data and I can't make buffering. Will it change anything I somehow put "GetPackets" function in a separate QThread?

Comment: Buffering needs to wait for some amount of data to let's play the data, for example accumulate 300 milliseconds of sound and only with that amount available start playing, after started keeps free to use the buffer until it has no more data, then reset to initial state. It's somewhat complex but i'm already done in [my library](https://github.com/antonypro/AudioStreaming/blob/master/AudioStreamingLibCore/AudioStreamingLibCore/audiooutput.cpp).For now i can't do better for you but i hope in some hours i can edit my answer accordingly ;)

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot for your help! At least, now I can play and record. :)

Comment: The buffer does work! :) But it seems that freezes depend on the number of packets that is put as a parameter to the function "GetPackets". If I put 1000ms to "write" and 125 to "GetPackets" (also 1000ms), I get awful freezes and 5 seems to be ideal. But sometimes playback freezes for the time that is set in "write" function, not random. I don't understand it. :)

Comment: You're using `waitForReadyRead` in yours `GetPackets` function. Note this will block the whole thread from run any code until it exits, including playing audio with `AudioOutput` and recording, if all lives in the same thread, the general advice is get rid of `waitFor...` functions, if it's really needed to use `waitForReadyRead`, put it in a separate thread or put the audio output in a different thread. I don't found any problems in playback audio myself and i don't use any blocking function. :)

Comment: Excellent! It works perfectly! I used waitForReadyRead, because last week it made packets to be played but now I don't need it. Thanks a lot! :)