# How to save recordings to *.wav?

Tags: qt, wav

I trying to change my code to save recordings to wav-files. Later i have to import this to MATLAB. 
Its works to save like .*pcm or.*wav. But I want play it with (example VLC Player) external player.

```
QAudioFormat format;
Conf values;
format.setSampleRate(values.getSampRate());
format.setChannelCount(values.getChannel());
format.setSampleSize(values.getSampSize());
format.setCodec(values.getCodec());
format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
```

in config-file i have configuration:

```
samp_rate=88200
channel=1
samp_size=24
codec=Audio/PCM
byte_order=QAudioFormat::LittleEndian
sample_type=QAudioFormat::SignedInt
```

Saving file looks:

```
m_audio->startrecording(fn+".pcm");
```

I changed pcm to wav - file will be recorded, but I cant open it with VLC (just import to Audacity with manual input of sample Rate, ByteOrder). Its because of RAW-data? how can able to save my recording like wav-file included sample-size, sampl-rate ...?

Audio.cpp

```
// ************************************************************************************************
// Audio-Class
// ************************************************************************************************

#include "Audio.h"
#include "Conf.h"
#include "Measure.h"

// ************************************************************************************************

Audio::Audio(Conf *conf)
{
    m_conf = conf;
    AudioRecord();
}

// ************************************************************************************************
//Initialization and signal-slot connection

void Audio::AudioRecord()
{

QAudioFormat format;
Conf values;
format.setSampleRate(values.getSampRate());
format.setChannelCount(values.getChannel());
format.setSampleSize(values.getSampSize());
format.setCodec(values.getCodec());
format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

QAudioDeviceInfo info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
if (!info.isFormatSupported(format))
{
    qWarning() << "Default format not supported";
    format = info.nearestFormat(format);
}

m_audio = new QAudioInput(format, this);
connect(m_audio, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), this, SLOT(handleStateChanged(QAudio::State)));

}

// ************************************************************************************************
//Start recording method

void Audio::startrecording(QString rec_file_path)
{
    m_file.setFileName(rec_file_path);
    m_file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    m_audio->start(&m_file);
}

// ************************************************************************************************
//Stop recording

void Audio::stoprecording()
{
    m_audio->stop();
    m_file.close();
}

// ************************************************************************************************
//Recording DEBUG output

void Audio::handleStateChanged(QAudio::State newState)
{
    switch (newState)
    {
        case QAudio::StoppedState:
            if (m_audio->error() != QAudio::NoError)
            {
                qDebug() << "Error!!";
            } else
            {
                qDebug() << "Finished recording";
            }
            break;

        case QAudio::ActiveState:
            qDebug() << "Started recording";
            break;

        default:

            break;
    }
}

// ************************************************************************************************
```

Audio.h

```
// ************************************************************************************************
// Audio-HEADER-file
// ************************************************************************************************

#ifndef AUDIO_H
#define AUDIO_H

// ************************************************************************************************
// Includes

#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include "Conf.h"
#include <QAudioInput>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QTimer>


// ************************************************************************************************
// Define

#define SAVE_AUDIO_PATH "/home/nikitajarocky/workspace/QT/UART_PC/IO/"

// ************************************************************************************************
// Class variables and methods

class Audio : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Audio(Conf *conf);
    void start(QString file_name);
    void stop();
    void startrecording(QString);
    void stoprecording();

signals:

public slots:
    void handleStateChanged(QAudio::State);
    void AudioRecord();

private:
    Conf *m_conf;
    Conf *m_samp_rate;    
    QAudioInput *m_audio;
    QFile m_file;
};

// ************************************************************************************************

#endif // AUDIO_H
```

Comment: You need to write the header (usually 44 bytes long) of the raw data to turn it in `wav` format. To do this i use a class based on code found on internet. The use is simple, call the constructor with filename and format, feed it with your raw audio data, then call close function or let the destructor do it! See here (Ignore the `AudioOutput` class) https://stackoverflow.com/a/50112936/2014561

Comment: Thank you very much Antonio, I try to change my Code!

Comment: Hello, can i convert pcm to wav in MATLAB? How can I do it?

Comment: I don't use MATLAB, so i don't know how conversions works there. But are you able to create a `.wav` file from raw data and play it with VLC media player? Are you facing problems when import the `.wav` file to MATLAB? Please give more info! ;)

Comment: Hello Antonio, I tryed to integrate your code to my (QT) but I get lot of errors. My AudioRecord.cpp looks so: (look above in addition!)

Comment: Please see my answer!

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler approach is use [`QAudioRecorder`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiorecorder.html), it handles the writing of the header and also handles the audio capture.

It saves you from big changes, if your goal is only recording.

See the example:

#### audio.h:

```
#ifndef AUDIO_H
#define AUDIO_H

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtMultimedia>

class Audio : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Audio(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Audio();

public slots:
    QStringList audioInputs();
    bool record(const QString &path, const QString &audio_input = QString());
    void stop();

private:
    QAudioRecorder *m_recorder;
};

#endif // AUDIO_H
```

#### audio.cpp:

```
#include "audio.h"

Audio::Audio(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_recorder = new QAudioRecorder(this);
}

Audio::~Audio()
{
    stop();
}

QStringList Audio::audioInputs()
{
    return m_recorder->audioInputs();
}

bool Audio::record(const QString &path, const QString &audio_input)
{
    QAudioEncoderSettings audio_settings;
    audio_settings.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    audio_settings.setChannelCount(1);
    audio_settings.setSampleRate(44100);

    m_recorder->setEncodingSettings(audio_settings);
    m_recorder->setOutputLocation(path);
    m_recorder->setAudioInput(audio_input);

    m_recorder->record();

    if (m_recorder->state() == QAudioRecorder::RecordingState)
    {
        qDebug() << "Recording...";
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << qPrintable(m_recorder->errorString());
        return false;
    }
}

void Audio::stop()
{
    if (m_recorder->state() == QAudioRecorder::RecordingState)
    {
        m_recorder->stop();
        qDebug() << "Recording stopped";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Nothing to stop";
    }
}
```

Usage example (recording 5 seconds):

```
#include <QtCore>
#include "audio.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Audio audio;
    audio.record("file.wav");
    QTimer::singleShot(5 * 1000, &audio, &Audio::stop);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer above!

Comment: Thank you very much for your work! But where I should to write a header? The importan think is to make WAV file, that I can later inspect with MATLAB!

Comment: Parallel to audiorecord I'm recording a text data via UART (see below)

Comment: Please note that `QAudioRecorder` is a high level recorder, you don't need to write directly the header because `QAudioRecorder` does it for you based on the encoder settings. The above example create a `.wav` file of the device `audio_input`(if no audio input is passed, it uses the default device), so start recording with `record(wav_path)` function and stop with `stop()` function!

Comment: Related: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-110790 -- FR for allowing QAudioRecorder to accept a QIODevice audio source to allow doing stuff with the audio before writing it to a container file.